# How to remove waiting cursor from textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Whenever I load windows form with text box, I'm get waiting cursor blinking in first textbox, but I waiting to blink when I click on that textbox.

This is how textbox code is looking like:

```
this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(166, 51);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(122, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 3;
```

Could anyone please tell me how I make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the focus to your first input field(textbox) by using TextBox1.Focus();

If you don't want any other textbox to be focused, you need to add an element that has Focus method implemented and use its Focus like a picture box. The easiest would be to add an invisible textbox and set the focus to it.

Comment: Whenever I make any focussed textbox invisibe, then focus automatically sets on different visible textbox with lower TabIndex value. Could you please me what I should do now?

Comment: what else do you have on the page other than textbox?

Comment: labels and buttons. I tried to move the focus to label, but it is still showing focus on textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the textbox is the first control to get focus.

Do you wish to have the focus on a different control, or not have the text box focussed?

Comment: Not have the text box focussed.

Comment: What do you wish to have focussed then when the form opens? Something has to be focussed...

Comment: Is it possible to shift focus to label control?

Comment: Nope, label can receive focus.